# Firebase Database Update Every 1 hour Using AWS lambda function

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my scenario i need to update firebase database every 1 hour.so i decided to run this in AWS lamda function because of no schedule trigger in cloud function.
Below is my code unable  to add firebase library to AWS Lamda function .

```
        'use strict';


         import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
         var Firebase = require('firebase');
         exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
        // TODO implement

        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;  //<---Important

         var config = {
         apiKey: "AIzaSy########################",
         authDomain: "########.firebaseapp.com",
         databaseURL: "https://a########.firebaseio.com",
         projectId: "aws#####",
         storageBucket: "",
         messagingSenderId: "83526964121"
         };
```

getting below error:

Cannot find module 'firebase'"

"errorMessage": "Unexpected token import",
  "errorType": "SyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    " ^^^^^^",
    "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import",
    "createScript (vm.js:56:10)",

**Cannot find module 'firebase'"**

***How to add Firebase module to Aws Lamda function.Please give me a hint..
Thanks in advance***

Comment: what will you do in your schedule trigger? call the a firebase http function or directly write to the database. ?

Comment: also avoid adding your firebase credentials in public forums.

Comment: call the a firebase http function or directly write to the database.?  How to call every 1 hour.I would like to write lamda function to execute write every 1 hour data

Comment: @UmarHussain Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

if your admin is imported in your lamda function successfully just initialize it with credentials (json file or required fields). See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup .

You don't need firebase dependency to do it since lamda function is not visible to users it can use admin access to your database.

Now when your admin sdk is initialize you just need to get the database reference like this (javascript style) :

```
let db= admin.database();
```

Now you have reference to the database and you can easily write to the any location since admin has full access to your database.

```
db.ref().child('/someNode').set({"key":"value"});
```

Comment: I have only that issue how to import firebase admin sdk into my lamda function.